# Don't run maximize. That I can do

Tags: equation-solving, maximize

good day.

Please, if someone could help me about one problem that I have.

**How could I maximize the expression and obtained nu and nm? and if possible what would be the expressions of nu and nm if don't use value numeric of parámeter**

```
ku = 1; km = 0.00001; \[Epsilon]u = 0.0003; \[Epsilon]m = 0.00045; \[Alpha] = 0.95; \[Lambda]m = 0.00013; \[Lambda]u = 1;  (*For*)  ` \[Mu] = [5000,10000] ;`

Maximize[{(-((
pm \[Epsilon]u^2 \[Mu] Log[pm/km])/(\[Epsilon]m Log[pu/ku])) + (pu \[Epsilon]u \[Lambda]m \[Mu] + (-pu \[Lambda]m + pm \[Lambda]u) Log[pu/ku])/\[Lambda]u)/(\[Epsilon]u \[Lambda]m), ku < pu <= ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) && km (pu/ku)^(\[Epsilon]m/\[Epsilon]u (1 - \[Alpha])) < pm <= km E^(\[Epsilon]m/(\[Epsilon]u^2 \[Mu]) (Log[pu/ku])^2)}, {pm,pu}, Reals]
```

Thanks too much.

Comment: Note: "` \[Mu] = [5000,10000] ;`" is a syntax error. Presumably should read: "` \[Mu] = [5000,10000] ;`" However, then the target function is vector valued and this can not be maximized.

Comment: @DanielHuber it's also using square brackets which is wrong too. It should have braces if a list / vector was intended.

Comment: About \ [Mu] I try to explain that this parameter should have a value between 5000 and 10000.  Will there one form that it was resolved?..............

Maximize[{(-((
    pm \[Epsilon]u^2 \[Mu] Log[pm/km])/(\[Epsilon]m Log[pu/ku])) + (
   pu \[Epsilon]u \[Lambda]m \[Mu] + (-pu \[Lambda]m + 
       pm \[Lambda]u) Log[pu/
      ku])/\[Lambda]u)/(\[Epsilon]u \[Lambda]m), 
  ku < pu <= ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) && 
   km (pu/ku)^(\[Epsilon]m/\[Epsilon]u (1 - \[Alpha])) < pm <= 
    km E^(\[Epsilon]m/(\[Epsilon]u^2 \[Mu]) (Log[pu/ku])^2)}, {pm, 
  pu}, Reals]